# SQL Server 2008 Query - table join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm having trouble getting the results I want from a SQL Server 2008 query.  Query 1 produces the results I want for [GeneralErrors] and Query 2 produces the correct results for [RehabErrors] but I really need them both on the same row.  When I try and combine the two queries in Query 3, my results for [GeneralErrors] is incorrect but of the way I'm going the tables.

Query1:

```
SELECT
        ReviewID, 
        SUM(CASE Score_CorrectID_Accuracy WHEN 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE Score_ProperlyIdentified_Accuracy WHEN 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GeneralErrors
    FROM  
        Reviews
    WHERE 
        (UserID IS NOT NULL AND UserID <> '')
    GROUP BY 
        Reviews.ReviewID

Results:

ReviewID    GeneralErrors
7           0
8           0
9           0
10          0
11          0
12          9
13          0
14          0
15          4
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT 
         Reviews.ReviewID
        ,COUNT(RehabMetricsCalls.ReviewID) AS RehabErrors
    FROM    RehabMetrics INNER JOIN
             RehabMetricsCalls ON RehabMetrics.RehabMetricID = RehabMetricsCalls.RehabMetricID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
             Reviews ON RehabMetricsCalls.ReviewID = Reviews.ReviewID   
    WHERE 
        (UserID IS NOT NULL AND UserID <> '')
    GROUP BY 
        Reviews.ReviewID

Results:

ReviewID    RehabErrors
7           3
8           0
9           0
10          0
11          0
12          5
13          5
14          0
15          4
```

Query 3:
My attempt at combining the two queries which produces incorrect results

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        Reviews.ReviewID
        ,SUM(CASE Score_CorrectID_Accuracy WHEN 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE Score_ProperlyIdentified_Accuracy WHEN 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE Score_MiniMiranda_Accuracy WHEN 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE Score_Tone_Accuracy WHEN 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE Score_Accuracy_Accuracy WHEN 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE Score_Notepad_Accuracy WHEN 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +        
        CASE Score_PCAResponsive_Accuracy WHEN 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE Score_AWGInfo_Accuracy WHEN 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE Complaint_Accuracy WHEN 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GeneralErrors
        ,COUNT(RehabMetricsCalls.ReviewID) AS RehabErrors
    FROM    RehabMetrics INNER JOIN
             RehabMetricsCalls ON RehabMetrics.RehabMetricID = RehabMetricsCalls.RehabMetricID INNER JOIN
             Reviews ON RehabMetricsCalls.ReviewID = Reviews.ReviewID   
    WHERE 
        (UserID IS NOT NULL AND UserID <> '')
    GROUP BY 
        Reviews.ReviewID
```

Desired results:

```
ReviewID    GeneralErrors   RehabErrors
    7           0               3
    12          45              5
    13          0               5
    15          16              4
```

Comment: That long sum in the 3th query with all the case, it's different from the first query. Why would you expect the same results? And you might want to use a `COUNT(DISTINCT RehabMetricsCalls.RehabMetricID)` for RehabErrors?

Comment: Btw, to get all the same ReviewId's in the 3th query you would have to select from Reviews and then left join the other 2 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do  a join..

```
;with Firstquery  as
(
SELECT
 ReviewID, 
 SUM(CASE Score_CorrectID_Accuracy WHEN 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
CASE Score_ProperlyIdentified_Accuracy WHEN 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GeneralErrors
 FROM  
 Reviews
 WHERE 
(UserID IS NOT NULL AND UserID <> '')
 GROUP BY 
Reviews.ReviewID
)
,Secondquery as
(
SELECT 
  Reviews.ReviewID
 ,COUNT(RehabMetricsCalls.ReviewID) AS RehabErrors
FROM    RehabMetrics INNER JOIN
   RehabMetricsCalls ON RehabMetrics.RehabMetricID = RehabMetricsCalls.RehabMetricID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
 Reviews ON RehabMetricsCalls.ReviewID = Reviews.ReviewID   
 WHERE 
 (UserID IS NOT NULL AND UserID <> '')
 GROUP BY 
  Reviews.ReviewID
)
select 
fs.reviewid,fs.generalerrors,sq.rehaberrors
from
firstquery fs
join
secondquery sq
on fs.reviewid=sq.reviewid
```

Comment: sq.generalerrors should be sq.rehaberrors.  Thanks very much

Comment: Thanks Updated now ,thats a mistake when typing